# What does $\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^2+ 1)$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I know that $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ but how would one generally interpret the expression: $$\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^2+ 1)$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what $\mathbb F_2[x]$ is? If so, do you know what $(x^2 + 1)$ stands for?

Comment: Do you know what ideals and quotient rings are?

Comment: @MeesdeVries I think that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients of either 0 or 1 for each term, I think $(x^2 + 1)$ is just a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Comment: @AlexMathers Also yeah I know about those as well

Comment: @silverjoe, actually $(x^2 + 1)$ is the ideal generated by $x^2 + 1$ -- that is, it is the ideal $\{P \cdot(x^2 + 1) \mid P \in \mathbb F_2[x]\}$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Oh I see, I see. Would that mean that $\mathbb{F}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ denotes the set of elements in $\mathbb{F}_2$ but not in the ideal generated by $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: @silverjoe, it is the quotient of $\mathbb F_2[x]$ by the ideal $(x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: No, the elements of $\Bbb F[x]/(x^2+1)$ are perhaps best visualized as expressions of form $a+bx$, where $a$ and $b$ are in $\Bbb F$. You add componentwise, in the obvious way; but in multiplication, every time you see an $x^2$, you have to replace it by $-1$, which is equal as I’m sure you know, to $1$ in $\Bbb F$

Comment: Roughly speaking, $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ is the enlargement of the ring $\Bbb{F}_2$ obtained by adjoining a new element $x$ that satisfies $x^2 + 1 = 0$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries oh i see, thanks that makes more sense

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring